# Routing with dashes and non-english characters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a specific routing need that I can't get to work. I've found quite a few answers here on StackOverflow that takes me a bit on the way, but not all the way.

Im naming my controllers and actions in the standard C# way, i.e. the first letter of every word is uppercase:

> MyController.MyAction()

To reach this action method, I'd like all of these urls to work:

```
/my-controller/my-action
/my-cöntroller/my-äction
/MyController/MyAction
/MyCöntroller/MyÄction
```

(the two last ones are not super important though...)

So there's two things here:

1. Dashes may be used to separate the words (for readability and SEO
   purposes).
2. Some non-english characters can be used (all replacements
       specified - no "magic").

I want to create the links with helpers like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("My link text", "MyController", "MyAction")
```

i.e. the standard way, and this will create the following link:

```
/my-controller/my-action
```

Hopefully this could be done without making my routing configuration too messy (e.g. with one route for every action or something), or putting attributes on all action methods, but if thats the only solution I'd like to know.

What I've tried so far is implementing a custom route class overriding GetRouteData() and GetVirtualPath(). It got me closer but not all the way, but I might do something wrong

I had an idea for solving the problem with non-english characters by doing the replacement before the routing is performed, but I haven't found a way to do this yet ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16192657/replace-character-in-url-before-routing-in-asp-net-mvc)).

I'd be really greatful if someone could help me with this, or at least point me in the right direction! :)

**Edit:** Note that the example urls above are just to describe what I want. In reality there is a lot of urls that must be handled, so I'd prefer some generic solution and not one involving one route for every action or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create your resource file

   ```
   Name            Value
   myaction1   my-äction   
   myaction2   my-action   
   mycontroller1   my-cöntroller   
   mycontroller2   my-controller
   ```
2. Add following routes in RegisterRoute method in global.asax

   routes.MapRoute(
                      name: "route1",
                      url: Resources.Actions.mycontroller1 + "/" + Resources.Actions.myaction1 ,
                      defaults: new { controller = "mycontroller1", action = "myaction1" }
                  );

   ```
           routes.MapRoute(
              name: "route2",
              url: Resources.Actions.mycontroller2 + "/" + Resources.Actions.myaction2,
              defaults: new { controller = "mycontroller2", action = "myaction2" }
          );
   ```
3. In controller,

   ```
    [HttpGet]
       public ActionResult myaction1()
       {

           return View("");
       }

   [HttpGet]
   public ActionResult myaction2()
   {
       return View("");
   }
   ```
4. In _Layout.cshtml

   @Html.ActionLink(Resources.Actions.myaction1, "myaction1", "mycontroller1")
      @Html.ActionLink(Resources.Actions.myaction2, "myaction2", "mycontroller2")

Comment: Thanks for the answer asb, but that won't work for me. I will have a lot of urls and the combination of with/without non-english characters and so on will force me to have a huge amount of routes using this solution. Plus I'd have to add new routes every time I add new actions. I've updated my description to clarify this.