# How to handle old aspx url with question mark '?' in new mvc website without using IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, redirect

I have moved my pages of my website from aspx to mvc.
I already have my old links in social media.
After my mvc changes are published, my old URLs stop working, which is exactly the problem.

Im using plesk and this edition does not have any settings to redirect URLs. So I dont think i can make use of redirection in IIS

My old URLs: https://www.abc123.com/movie?123

My new URLs: https://www.abc123.com/title/123

I have workaround with in MVC to handle aspx URL if my old url has proper query string like https://www.abc123.com/movie?id=123

```
        [Route("movie")]
        [Route("Title/{id}")]
        public ActionResult Index(int id)
        {
        }
```

But this is not working with URL https://www.abc123.com/movie?123 as question mark (?) cannot be used in Route configs.

Kindly help me to handle this problem of mine.

Comment: Pls check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3763398/how-can-i-change-a-route-value-then-redirect-to-that-route

Comment: @AA I used OnException to redirect to proper new URL. But OnActionExecuting  makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved my problem:

In controller of title I added below code,

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
            if (((HttpRequestWrapper)Request).CurrentExecutionFilePath.ToLower() != "/movie") {return; }
            var id = Request.QueryString[null];
            int titleid;
            if (!int.TryParse(id, out titleid)) return;
            Response.RedirectPermanent("~/title/" + titleid);
        }
```

Thanks to AA